# Can I create a listening TCP socket using raw sockets in Linux?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I would like to create a listening TCP socket where I could control when it responds to the client with the first SYN+ACK after it receives the initial SYN packet from the client.

I want to do this to introduce some delays or ignore some initial SYN packets. I can do this using iptables at the moment, but I'm wondering if this could be done using the OS socket interface.

Note that if I use a normal TCP socket, once the server calls listen() on the socket descriptor, the OS will establish the connection when a client connects to it.

I am wondering then if I could use raw sockets to implement this behavior. All the examples I have seen so far about raw sockets are about active sockets (client to server) and not passive sockets (listening sockets).

Answer (score 5):

You could theoretically write your own TCP implementation over raw sockets. But the kernel will still respond to any incoming TCP packets before your raw socket gets a copy. So you'd have to work around this by using iptables or something to block the kernel from seeing the packets you're interested in.

I think it would be easier to do this in a kernel module via the netfilter interface (which may be what you're already doing). You could also check out `libnetfilter_queue` which might work if you really want to do it in userspace.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Honeynet project, they implement low cost virtual machines with a basic IP stack to adjust the TCP protocol operation.

https://projects.honeynet.org/sebek/browser/linux-2.6/trunk/src